# MYSQL- OR SQL Optimization

Tags: mysql

I select data from one table.

This query does a selection using indexed fields (col1、col2、col3、col4、col5):

```
SELECT * 
FROM `table` 
WHERE (col1=1339664 or col2=1339664 or col3=1339664 or col4=1339664) 
  AND col5= 932111;
```

Is the any way how to optimize this query?

I will appreciate your help

Comment: *All have indexes* Separate indexes, each by one column? They're about nothing for this query. Maybe only the composite index by `(col5, col1, col2, col3, col4)` (or the same with another columns order, but `col5` always first) will help...

Answer (score 1):

The only index that is ever going to be used on that query is the one on col5.

What will run indexed is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `table` 
WHERE col1=1339664
  AND col5= 932111
UNION
SELECT * 
FROM `table` 
WHERE col2=1339664
  AND col5= 932111
UNION
SELECT * 
FROM `table` 
WHERE col3=1339664
  AND col5= 932111
UNION
SELECT * 
FROM `table` 
WHERE col4=1339664
  AND col5= 932111;
```

For that query you will need the following indexes:

```
(col5, col1)
(col5, col2)
(col5, col3)
(col5, col4)
```

Comment: yes, It's getting faster. But  Extar Using temporary .